# Picamera or Webcam Web Interface

Tags: pi-2, ssh, raspicam, vnc

I read in the [Raspberry Pi Official Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-picamera/worksheet/) that you cannot preview the `picamera` using `SSH` and `VNC`. The doc states:

> Note that the camera preview only works when a monitor is connected to
>   the Pi, so remote access (such as SSH and VNC) will not allow you to
>   see the camera preview.

But, I have googled, and I have found a tweak to preview `picamera` on PC running on `Ubuntu`. Here is the [link](http://zacharybears.com/low-latency-raspberry-pi-video-streaming/). The tutorial uses **`NetCat`** on `Ubuntu`.

I cannot find **`NetCat`** for my Windows machine. Is there any way possible to do what I want on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long detailed research, I have found this full [setup](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/) tutorial. It has some limitations though, that I've read in a review in another website, but it works very well for my job.

Comment: @geek1011 You should check this link. It might benefit you somehow

Answer (score 0):

Netcat **is** available for Windows. See: https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/

Comment: @OsamaAbbas The same way as nc on Linux

Comment: Not working for me on Windows

Comment: @OsamaAbbas What is happening?